# Anchor links are not all pointing to their name counterparts

Tags: html, anchor

I have a site where a few of the anchor links are not landing on the right spots of the second page while some are. I've quadruple checked the names for accuracy, ran it through the validator, etc but with no luck.

On the page http://webnamix.com/clients/pmgideas/index.php there is a link "Working with PMG saves you money" that is supposed to go to the #benefit bits of the faq page but it drops me to the bottom of the page.  Same goes with "consultants who offer 'moment in time' analysis or advice".  However, the "Gil Price's background" link seems to be doing just fine.

Can I please get a second pair of eyes on why this is happening?

Comment: You shouldn't use `<a name="...">` at all! Use `id="..."` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any of them working. Can you turn off the CSS and try again or create a separate node and see if the same code works?

Answer (score 0):

the #benefit anchor works fine. The page lands to the bottom which is the most possible to scroll down.
If you want you can activate/open the "benefits" anchor by writing javascript code. This will increment the bottom size, so it can point exactly where you want to land.